# Inserting into Set changing the order of Elements in an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

```
@search_results = Array.new
duplicates = Set.new
results.each { |result|    @search_results.push(result) unless duplicates.add?(result[:url]) }
```

This piece of code is garbling the order of elements in the array @search_results. Why would inserting the same element in a set and an array change the insertion order for Array? Seems like some issue with element references. Can someone explain?

Edit 1:
I am using an Array. Sorry for the earlier typo. I double checked by code and it uses Array too (there is no push method for Hash anyways)

Comment: Where does the variable "results" come from? It may be that its order is indeterminate (e.g., if it is a Hash or Set).

Comment: Please define 'garbled': what order to you expect them to be in? How was the order changed?

Comment: @chuck - results is an array.
@Lolindrath - I expect the order to be the same as the order in which it is inserted. Instead, it gives a random order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of elements in a Hash is not guaranteed. You'll have to sort the keys if you want a guaranteed order.

This is supposedly fixed in Ruby 1.9 I believe.

**Edit:** I'm assuming your results in an Array, if its a Hash then order isn't guaranteed and you'll have to sort the keys, here's what my test looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -W

require 'pp'
require 'set'

results = Array.new

results << {:url => 'http://lifehacker.com'}
results << {:url => 'http://stackoverflow.com'}
results << {:url => 'http://43folders.com'}
results << {:url => 'http://lolindrath.com'}
results << {:url => 'http://stackoverflow.com'}
results << {:url => 'http://lifehacker.com'}



@search_results = Array.new
duplicates = Set.new

results.each { |result| @search_results.push(result) unless duplicates.add?(result[:url])}

puts "## @search_results"
pp @search_results
```

If I run that, here's the result:

```
## @search_results
[{:url=>"http://stackoverflow.com"}, {:url=>"http://lifehacker.com"}]
```

I found that odd, so just to be sure, I put a `.nil?` add the end of `.add?` and here was my result:

```
## @search_results
[{:url=>"http://lifehacker.com"},
 {:url=>"http://stackoverflow.com"},
 {:url=>"http://43folders.com"},
 {:url=>"http://lolindrath.com"}]
```

Now *that* was what I was expecting: is this what you mean by "garbled"?

**Edit 2:** Upon further investigation, I think this is because of Ruby's super strict rules when converting non-Boolean data to Booleans (see [Ruby Gotchas on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#.22Gotchas.22) and [Stack Overflow, of course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about)) so that basically anything that only false is really false and everything else is true. so the `.nil?` is converting it explicitly to true/false.

```
irb(main):007:0> puts "zero is true" if 0
zero is true
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> puts "zero is false" unless 0
=> nil
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I meant. Pretty strange that adding .nil? makes it work.

Comment: The issue was that .add? returns nil on SUCCESS and the object on FAILURE, so you were testing the revers condition, since nil is falsey in Ruby

Comment: that incorrect, it returns nil if the object is already in the set - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Set.html#M001630

Answer (score 0):

Garbled how?  What kind of object is `results`?  If `results` is a `Set` or a `Hash`, then you're not guaranteed that any two traversals of `results` will be in the same order.

Also, you could do

```
@search_results = results.uniq
```

if `results` is an `Array` to get all the unique results.

```
------------------------------------------------------------- Array#uniq
     array.uniq   -> an_array
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Returns a new array by removing duplicate values in self.

        a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
        a.uniq   #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```