# Why in Ruby, a || 1 will throw an error when `a` is undefined, but a = a || 1 will not?

Tags: ruby, exception, undefined, undefined-behavior

When `a` is undefined, then `a || 1` will throw an error, but `a = a || 1` will not.  Isn't that a little bit inconsistent?

```
irb(main):001:0> a
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from c:/ruby/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'

irb(main):002:0> a || 1
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object
        from (irb):2
        from c:/ruby/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'

irb(main):003:0> a = a || 1
=> 1
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462407/ruby-edge-cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a
```

Here, you are evaluating `a`, which isn't defined. Therefore, you get an exception.

```
a || 1
```

Here, you *still* have to evaluate `a` to determine the value of the boolean expression. Just like above, `a` isn't defined. Therefore, you get an exception.

```
a = a || 1
```

Here, `a` *is* defined. It is defined to be an uninitialized local variable. In Ruby, uninitialized variables evaluate to `nil`, so the right hand side of the assignment expression evaluates to `nil || 1` which evaluates to `1`, so the return value of the assignment expression is `1` and the side effect is that `a` is initialized to `1`.

EDIT: It seems that there is some confusion on when variables get defined and when they get initialized in Ruby. The get defined at *parse time* but initialized at *runtime*. You can see it here:

```
 foo # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

`foo` is undefined.

```
if false
  foo = 'This will never get executed'
end
```

At this point, `foo` is defined, even though the line will never get executed. The fact that the line never gets executed is completely irrelevant, because the interpreter has nothing to do with this anyway: local variables are defined by the parser, and the parser obviously sees this line.

```
foo # => nil
```

There is no error, because `foo` is defined, and it evaluates to `nil` because it is uninitialized.

Comment: +1, though I think saying "It is defined to be an uninitialized local variable." is a bit confusing. When you do `var = expr`, you're not defining `var` to be uninitialized. You're defining var to be the value of `expr`. It's just that while `expr` evaluates, `var` happens to be uninitialized, which means that any references to `var` inside `expr` will evaluate to nil.

Comment: @sepp2k: They are two very separate steps. Variable definition occurs in the parser, initialization in the interpreter. Depending on the Ruby implementation, there can be a significant time between the two events. In BlueRuby, for example, Ruby sourcecode gets parsed into BRIL (BlueRuby Intermediate Language), which then gets stored in a database, when you *install* a Ruby program. It could be *years* until somebody actually *runs* the program. All this time, the variable was defined but not initialized. The two things could even happen on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a || 1`, you're asking it to look for the value of `a` which is undefined.

When you do `a = a || 1` you're asking it to look for the value of assigning `a` to `a` which doesn't seem to give an error.

So, although weird, I don't believe it to be inconsistent.

Comment: This is wrong. `a = a || 1` does not parse as `(a = a) || 1`. It parses as `a = (a || 1)`, so the result of "assigning a to a" has nothing to do with it, because a is never assigned to a.

Comment: @sepp2k: I wasn't trying to imply that at all.  I'm sorry if I confused you. I believe that Jörg has explained it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
if !(defined? a) then
    a = 1
end
```

It might be simpler to declare the value with 1 as default.