# How come (a_method || :other) returns :other only when assigning to a var called a_method?

Tags: ruby

Given the following method:

```
def some_method
  :value
end
```

The following statements work as I would expect:

```
some_method || :other
# => :value

x = some_method || :other
# => :value
```

But the behaviour of the following statement perplexes me:

```
some_method = some_method || :other
# => :other
```

It creates a local variable called `some_method` as expected, and subsequent calls to `some_method` return the value of that local variable.  But why does it assign `:other` rather than `:value`?

I understand that it's probably not a smart thing to do, and can see how it might be ambiguous, but I thought the right-hand-side of the assignment should be evaluated prior to the assignment being considered...

I've tested this in Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.2 with identical results.

Cheers!

Paul

Comment: "I thought the right-hand-side of the assignment should be evaluated prior to the assignment". It is, but it is the right-hand side of the '=' sign, not the entire line. `some_method` will be evaluated to see if it has a "truthiness" first, and, if so, that will be returned. If not then `:other` will be considered. Boolean operators like `||` and `&&` sometimes seem arbitrary because of how a particular language determines "truth". For instance, Perl determines it differently than Ruby, so you have to be aware of the differences if you use both languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been similar questions, but not exactly the same. [Jörg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983379/why-in-ruby-a-1-will-throw-an-error-when-a-is-undefined-but-a-a-1-wi/2983677#2983677) here seems to hit the point, I'm quoting the relevant part:

> At this point, `foo` is defined, even
>   though the line will never get
>   executed. The fact that the line never
>   gets executed is completely
>   irrelevant, because the interpreter
>   has nothing to do with this anyway:
>   local variables are defined by the
>   parser, and the parser obviously sees
>   this line.

So, in your case, regardless of the fact that a method with the same name already exists, the parser sees `some_method` assignment and it automatically "tags" the identifier to be local variable. So, when interpreter starts evaluating the right-hand-side of the assignment, it already considers `some_method` to be local variable, not a method. Its value is unassigned (`nil` by default), so the result of `||` will be `:other`.

Comment: >>  already considers some_method to be local variable .. with a false value, hence :other being assigned.

Comment: Right (just with undefined rather than false value), I have edited the answer at the same time you wrote the comment. :)

Comment: @noodl: I think it'd be `nil`, not `false`.

Comment: @Andrew Yep, I meant "false-ish", not `false`. I think you're right about nil: `ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo = foo #=> nil`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer. Hopefully more accurate now.

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer is: your last statement is the same as

```
some_var = some_var || :other
```

because when you have a local variable in scope with the same name as a method, the interpreter gives the local variable precedence.