# Ruby forgets local variables during a while loop?

Tags: ruby, object, undefined

I'm processing a record-based text file: so I'm looking for a starting string which constitutes the start of a record: there is no end-of-record marker, so I use the start of the next record to delimit the last record.

So I have built a simple program to do this, but I see something which suprises me: it looks like Ruby is forgetting local variables exist - or have I found a programming error ? [although I don't think I have : if I define the variable 'message' before my loop I don't see the error].

Here's a simplified example with example input data and error message in comments:

```
flag=false
# message=nil # this is will prevent the issue.
while line=gets do
    if line =~/hello/ then
        if flag==true then
            puts "#{message}"
        end
        message=StringIO.new(line);
        puts message
        flag=true
    else
        message << line
    end
end

# Input File example:
# hello this is a record
# this is also part of the same record
# hello this is a new record
# this is still record 2
# hello this is record 3 etc etc
# 
# Error when running: [nb, first iteration is fine]
# <StringIO:0x2e845ac>
# hello
# test.rb:5: undefined local variable or method `message' for main:Object (NameError)
#
```

Comment: This is a great question. I've been coding ruby for at least a decade but I still couldn't see the root cause immediately. See my answer.

Comment: I have read through your answer - but I'll need to read it a few more times before it gets through to my thick skull. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is because message is defined inside the loop. At the end of the loop iteration "message" goes out of scope. Defining "message" outside of the loop stops the variable from going out of scope at the end of each loop iteration. So I think you have the right answer.

You could output the value of message at the beginning of each loop iteration to test whether my suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 30):

From the Ruby Programming Language:

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://bks0.books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&sig=ACfU3U1rnYKha_p7vEkpPm1Ow3o9RAM0nQ))</sub>

### Blocks and Variable Scope

Blocks define a new variable scope: variables created within a block exist only within that block and are undefined outside of the block. Be cautious, however; the local variables in a method are available to any blocks within that method. So if a block assigns a value to a variable that is already defined outside of the block, this does not create a new block-local variable but instead assigns a new value to the already-existing variable. Sometimes, this is exactly the behavior we want:

```
total = 0   
data.each {|x| total += x }  # Sum the elements of the data array
puts total                   # Print out that sum
```

Sometimes, however, we do not want to alter variables in the enclosing scope, but we do so inadvertently. This problem is a particular concern for block parameters in Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.8, if a block parameter shares the name of an existing variable, then invocations of the block simply assign a value to that existing variable rather than creating a new block-local variable. The following code, for example, is problematic because it uses the same identifier i as the block parameter for two nested blocks:

```
1.upto(10) do |i|         # 10 rows
  1.upto(10) do |i|       # Each has 10 columns
    print "#{i} "         # Print column number
  end
  print " ==> Row #{i}\n" # Try to print row number, but get column number
end
```

Ruby 1.9 is different: block parameters are always local to their block, and invocations of the block never assign values to existing variables. If Ruby 1.9 is invoked with the -w flag, it will warn you if a block parameter has the same name as an existing variable. This helps you avoid writing code that runs differently in 1.8 and 1.9.

Ruby 1.9 is different in another important way, too. Block syntax has been extended to allow you to declare block-local variables that are guaranteed to be local, even if a variable by the same name already exists in the enclosing scope. To do this, follow the list of block parameters with a semicolon and a comma-separated list of block local variables. Here is an example:

```
x = y = 0            # local variables
1.upto(4) do |x;y|   # x and y are local to block
                     # x and y "shadow" the outer variables
  y = x + 1          # Use y as a scratch variable
  puts y*y           # Prints 4, 9, 16, 25
end
[x,y]                # => [0,0]: block does not alter these
```

In this code, x is a block parameter: it gets a value when the block is invoked with yield. y is a block-local variable. It does not receive any value from a yield invocation, but it has the value nil until the block actually assigns some other value to it. The point of declaring these block-local variables is to guarantee that you will not inadvertently clobber the value of some existing variable. (This might happen if a block is cut-and-pasted from one method to another, for example.) If you invoke Ruby 1.9 with the -w option, it will warn you if a block-local variable shadows an existing variable.

Blocks can have more than one parameter and more than one local variable, of course. Here is a block with two parameters and three local variables:

```
hash.each {|key,value; i,j,k| ... }
```

Answer (score 17):

Contrary to some of the other answers, `while` loops don't actually create a new scope. The problem you're seeing is more subtle.

**Prerequisite knowledge: a brief scoping demo**

To help show the contrast, blocks passed to a method call *DO* create a new scope, such that a newly assigned local variable inside the block disappears after the block exits:

```
### block example - provided for contrast only ###
[0].each {|e| blockvar = e }
p blockvar  # NameError: undefined local variable or method
```

But `while` loops (like your case) are different, because a variable defined in the loop will persist:

```
arr = [0]
while arr.any?
  whilevar = arr.shift
end
p whilevar  # prints 0
```

**Summary of the "problem"**

The reason you get the error in your case is because the line that uses `message`:

```
puts "#{message}"
```

appears before any code that *assigns* `message`.

It's the same reason this code raises an error if `a` wasn't defined beforehand:

```
# Note the single (not double) equal sign.
# At first glance it looks like this should print '1',
#  because the 'a' is assigned before (time-wise) the puts.
puts a if a = 1
```

**Not Scoping, but Parsing-visibility**

The so-called "problem" - i.e. local-variable **visibility** within a single scope - is due to ruby's **parser**. Since we're only considering a single scope, scoping rules have **nothing** to do with the problem. At the parsing stage, the parser decides at which source locations a local variable is visible, and this visibility does *not* change during execution.

When determining if a local variable is defined (i.e. `defined?` returns true) at any point in the code, the parser checks the current scope to see if any code has assigned it before, even if that code has never run (the parser can't know anything about what has or hasn't run at the parsing stage). "Before" meaning: on a line above, or on the same line and to the left-hand side.

**An exercise to determine if a local is defined (i.e. visible)**

Note that the following only applies to local variables, not methods. (Determining whether a method is defined in a scope is more complex, because it involves searching included modules and ancestor classes.)

A concrete way to see the local variable behavior is to open your file in a text editor. Suppose also that by repeatedly pressing the left-arrow key, you can move your cursor backward through the entire file. Now suppose you're wondering whether a certain usage of `message` will raise the `NameError`. To do this, position your cursor at the place you're using `message`, then keep pressing left-arrow until you either:

1. reach the beginning of the current scope (you must understand ruby's scoping rules in order to know when this happens)
2. reach code that assigns `message`

If you've reached an assignment before reaching the scope boundary, that means your usage of `message` won't raise `NameError`. If you don't reach any assignment, the usage will raise `NameError`.

**Other considerations**

In the case a variable assignment appears in the code but isn't run, the variable is initialized to `nil`:

```
# a is not defined before this
if false
  # never executed, but makes the binding defined/visible to the else case
  a = 1
else
  p a  # prints nil
end
```

**While loop test case**

Here's a small test case to demonstrate the oddness of the above behavior when it happens in a while loop. The affected variable here is `dest_arr`.

```
arr = [0,1]
while n = arr.shift
  p( n: n, dest_arr_defined: (defined? dest_arr) )

  if n == 0
    dest_arr = [n]
  else
    dest_arr << n
    p( dest_arr: dest_arr )
  end
end
```

which outputs:

```
{:n=>0, :dest_arr_defined=>nil}
{:n=>1, :dest_arr_defined=>nil}
{:dest_arr=>[0, 1]}
```

The salient points:

- The first iteration is intuitive, `dest_arr` is initialized to `[0]`.
- But we need to pay close attention in the second iteration (when `n` is `1`):

  - At the beginning, `dest_arr` is undefined!
  - But when the code reaches the `else` case, `dest_arr` is visible again, because the interpreter sees that it was assigned 2 lines above.
  - Notice also, that `dest_arr` is only *hidden* at the start of the loop; its value is never lost (as evidenced by the final contents being `[0, 1]`).

This also explains why assigning your local before the `while` loop fixes the problem. The assignment doesn't need to be executed; it only needs to appear in the source code.

**Lambda example**

```
f1 = ->{ f2 }
f2 = ->{ f1 }
p f2.call()

# The following fails because the body of f1 tries to access f2 before an assignment for f2 was seen by the parser.
p f1.call()  # undefined local variable or method `f2'.
```

Fix this by putting an `f2` assignment before `f1`'s body. Remember, the assignment doesn't actually need to be executed!

```
f2 = nil  # Could be replaced by: if false; f2 = nil; end
f1 = ->{ f2 }
f2 = ->{ f1 }
p f2.call()
p f1.call()  # ok
```

**Method-masking gotcha**

Things get really hairy if you have a local variable with the same name as a method:

```
def dest_arr
  :whoops
end

arr = [0,1]
while n = arr.shift
  p( n: n, dest_arr: dest_arr )

  if n == 0
    dest_arr = [n]
  else
    dest_arr << n
    p( dest_arr: dest_arr )
  end
end
```

Outputs:

```
{:n=>0, :dest_arr=>:whoops}
{:n=>1, :dest_arr=>:whoops}
{:dest_arr=>[0, 1]}
```

A local variable assignment in a scope will "mask"/"shadow" a method call of the same name. (You can still call the method by using explicit parentheses or an explicit receiver.) So this is similar to the previous `while` loop test, except that instead of becoming undefined above the assignment code, the `dest_arr` *method* becomes "unmasked"/"unshadowed" so that the method is callable w/o parentheses. But any code after the assignment will see the local variable.

**Some best-practices we can derive from all this**

- Don't name local variables the same as method names in the same scope
- Don't put the initial assignment of a local variable inside the body of a `while` or `for` loop, or anything that causes execution to jump around within a scope (calling lambdas or `Continuation#call` can do this too). Put the assignment before the loop.

Comment: +1 Interesting insight about ruby's `while` and how it scopes its seemingly local variables. Have you found any "official" documentation on this behavior as to why this is specific to `while`?

Comment: @Matt I made an edit to clarify that the issue is *not* with scoping. We are only considering *one* scope. Loops are special because they don't conform to how the parser reads things left-to-right, top-to-bottom, i.e. loops cause execution to jump to the left or upward in the source code. Local-variable visibility within a scope is fixed at the parse stage. I don't know about official docs, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15111934/498594) might help.

Comment: Very nice. This explains why this loop never ends: `until defined?(foo) do foo=1 end` but this one does: `begin foo=1 end until defined?(foo)`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think this is a bug?  The interpreter is telling you that message may be undefined when that particular piece of code executes.

Comment: With respect: I don't think that's right. The interpreter is telling that message is not defined at this point. The first iteration (puts message) works.

This has to be due to the scoping rules in blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're surprised: on line 5 (assuming that the `message = nil` line isn't there), you potentially use a variable that the interpreter has never heard of before. The interpreter says "What's `message`? It's not a method I know, it's not a variable I know, it's not a keyword..." and then you get an error message.

Here's a simpler example to show you what I mean:

```
while line = gets do
  if line =~ /./ then
    puts message # How could this work?
    message = line
  end
end
```

Which gives:

```
telemachus ~ $ ruby test.rb < huh 
test.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `message' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Also, if you want to prepare the way for `message`, I would initialize it as `message = ''`, so that it's a string (rather than `nil`). Otherwise, if your first line *doesn't* match hello, you end up tring to add `line` to `nil` - which will get you this error:

```
telemachus ~ $ ruby test.rb < huh 
test.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: To clarify why I was suprised : the statement "message=StringIO.new(line);" HAS been run once before I get the 'undefined' message: (the program DOES output the first reference to message, just not subsequent iterations). I should have probably indicated that in my output. [will ammend now]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this :

```
message=''

while line=gets do
   if line =~/hello/ then
      # begin a new record 
      p message unless message == ''
      message = String.new(line)
   else
     message << line
  end
end

# hello this is a record
# this is also part of the same record
# hello this is a new record
# this is still record 2
# hello this is record 3 etc etc
```