# Confusion with the assignment operation inside a falsy `if` block

Tags: ruby, if-statement, nameerror

I was playing with the assignment operation within `if` blocks, and discovered the below result, which surprised me:

```
C:\>irb --simple-prompt
if false
x = 10
end
#=> nil
p x
nil
x.object_id
#=> 4
#=> nil
p y
NameError: undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object
        from (irb):5
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

In the above code you can see that the `x` local variable has been created even though it was only assigned to in the falsy `if` block. I tried to to see the content of `x` with `p x` which forced me to believe that assignment was not done, but the `x` variable exists. `x.object_id` also proved that is the case.

Now my question is how that `x` local variable was created even though the `if` block entry point is closed forever intentionally?

I expected the output of `p x` to be similar to the output from `p y`. But instead I got a surprising answer from `p x`.

Could someone explain to me how this concept works?

***EDIT***

No, here is another test. This is not the case with only `local` variables. The same happened with `instance` and `class` variables also. See the below:

```
class Foo
  def show
    @X = 10 if false
    p @X,"hi",@X.object_id
  end
end
#=> nil
Foo.new.show
nil
"hi"
4
#=> [nil, "hi", 4]

class Foo
  def self.show
    @@X = 10 if false
    p @@X,"hi",@@X.object_id
  end
end
#=> nil
Foo.show
nil
"hi"
4
#=> [nil, "hi", 4]
```

Successful case :

```
class Foo
  def self.show
    @@X = 10 if true
    p @@X,"hi",@@X.object_id
  end
end
#=> nil
Foo.show
10
"hi"
4
#=> [10, "hi", 4]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby, local variables are defined by the parser when it first encounters an assignment, and are then in scope from that point on.

Here's a little demonstration:

```
foo # NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object

if false
  foo = 42
end

foo # => nil
```

As you can see, the local variable *does* exist on line 7 even though the assignment on line 4 was never executed. It was, however, *parsed* and that's why the local variable `foo` exists. But because the assignment was never executed, the variable is uninitialized and thus evaluates to `nil` and not `42`.

In Ruby, most uninitialized or even non-existing variables evaluate to `nil`. This is true for local variables, instance variables and global variables:

```
defined? foo       #=> nil
local_variables    #=> []
if false
  foo = 42
end
defined? foo       #=> 'local-variable'
local_variables    #=> [:foo]
foo                #=> nil
foo.nil?           #=> true

defined? @bar      #=> nil
instance_variables #=> []
@bar               #=> nil
@bar.nil?          #=> true
# warning: instance variable @bar not initialized

defined? $baz      #=> nil
$baz               #=> nil
# warning: global variable `$baz' not initialized
$baz.nil?          #=> true
# warning: global variable `$baz' not initialized
```

It is, however, not true for class hierarchy variables and constants:

```
defined? @@wah     #=> nil
@@wah
# NameError: uninitialized class variable @@wah in Object

defined? QUUX      #=> nil
QUUX
# NameError: uninitialized constant Object::QUUX
```

This is a red herring:

```
defined? fnord     #=> nil
local_variables    #=> []
fnord
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `fnord' for main:Object
```

The reason why you get an error here is *not* that unitialized local variables don't evaluate to `nil`, it is that `fnord` is ambiguous: it could be *either* an argument-less message send to the default receiver (i.e. equivalent to `self.fnord()`) *or* an access to the local variable `fnord`.

In order to disambiguate that, you need to add a receiver or an argument list (even if empty) to tell Ruby that it is a message send:

```
self.fnord
# NoMethodError: undefined method `fnord' for main:Object
fnord()
# NoMethodError: undefined method `fnord' for main:Object
```

or make sure that the *parser* (*not* the evaluator) parses (*not* executes) an assignment before the usage, to tell Ruby that it is a local variable:

```
if false
  fnord = 42
end
fnord              #=> nil
```

And, of course, `nil` is an object (it is the only instance of class `NilClass`) and thus has an `object_id` method.

Comment: when I did the below `>> local_variables #=> [:name, :_]`. What is `:_` ?

Comment: Well, it's another local variable. I can't tell you where it comes from, you would have to show your entire code for that. However, if you tried that in IRb, then the answer is obvious: it's the local variable defined by IRb that always holds the value of the last expression that was evaluated.

Comment: Yes. I typed it in `IRB`. here is the code `>> local_variables
#=> [:_]
>> if false
>> name = "joy"
>> end
#=> nil
>> local_variables
#=> [:name, :_]`

Comment: Okay, so I tried it now - `local_variables
#=> [:_]
if false
name = "joy"
end
#=> nil
local_variables
#=> [:name, :_]
a = 2 + 3
#=> 5
local_variables
#=> [:a, :name, :_]
p :_
:_
#=> :_` But couldn't see any values in `:_` :(

Comment: The name of the variable is `_`. `:_` is a symbol literal denoting the name of the variable.

Comment: yes, you are right - here is my try `>> 2 + 3
=> 5
>> p "#{_}"
"5"
=> "5" `

Comment: Worth mentioning that this behavior is not just a Rubyism; it's an artifact of allowing variables to be used in the scope of their definition even before the definition itself (called "hoisting").  Javascript does the same thing: an undefined var raises a ReferenceError, but if you do `if (false) { var fnord=42; }`, a reference to `fnord` just returns `undefined` with no exception.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby always parses all of your code. It doesn't look at false as a sign to not parse what's inside, it evaluates it and sees that the code inside shouldn't be executed

Comment: Your hints is good! So `+1` from me. :)

Comment: eh? `if false ; TOTALCRAPGOESHERE ; end` results in silent `# ⇒ nil`.

Comment: Right. `TOTALCRAPGOESHERE` didn't get evaluated, expression returned `nil`

Comment: @enthrops Sorry, I accidentally read “parsed” as “tries to evaluate” instead of “parsed for syntax.” My fault.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has local variable "hoisting". If you have an assignment to a local variable anywhere within a method, then that variable exists everywhere within the method, even before the assignment, and even if the assignment is never actually executed. Before the variable is assigned, it has a value of `nil`.

Edit:

The above is not quite correct. Ruby does have a form of variable hoisting in that it will define a local variable when a local variable assignment is present, but not executed. The variable will not be found to be defined at points in the method above where the assignment occurs, however.

Comment: But how it enters into the `If` block whereas the entry point is locked with `false`. Who break that lock?

Comment: It is not the case with always `local` variables.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. Local variables only exist *after* they have been defined. You're probably thinking of JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15111934/2988 for a demonstration.

Comment: I was thinking of Ruby, not Javascript, and Ruby does have a form of variable hoisting. I see that you are correct, however, that the variable is only found to be defined later in the method than where the first variable assignment occurs. The variable is still hoisted, however, in that it is defined even if the assignment is NOT executed.

Comment: To clarify Jörg's comment above - "after" doesn't mean execution-wise, but appearance in the source code when read left-to-right, top-to-bottom.