# Strange meaning of || and ||= in Ruby (2.0, 1.9.3, jruby 1.7.4)

Tags: ruby, jruby

Consider the following irb snippet from a freshly-started session:

```
irb:01> baz            # => NameError, baz is not defined
irb:02> baz || baz = 0 # => NameError, baz is not defined
irb:03> baz            # => nil
```

`baz` was an undefined variable and trying to evaluate it produced a `NameError`.  Yet, somehow, after this operation, `baz` was defined, and has a value of `nil`.  Seemingly, the value `nil` was assigned to the variable `baz` even though no one (explicitly) asked for it to be.  Is there an underlying language reason why this behavior is desirable?

What is the rule that explains this behavior and other similarly confusing constructs, such as these:

```
irb:04> true if foo            # => NameError
irb:05> foo                    # => NameError; name still undefined
irb:06> foo = (true if foo)    # => nil
irb:07> foo                    # => nil; name defined as nil
irb:08> true || i = 0 || j = 2 # => i and j are nil; || appears nonlazy
irb:09> raise || quux = 1      # => RuntimeError, quux is nil
```

Comment: You're not actually using `||=` in any of your examples, question title is a bit misleading

Comment: Even more strangely: `>> spam # => NameError; >> spam ||= "eggs" # => "eggs"; >> spam # => "eggs"`. Inconsistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion with the assignment operation inside the fallacy \`if\` block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183576/confusion-with-the-assignment-operation-inside-the-fallacy-if-block)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it is desirable, but it comes from how Ruby parses the code. Whenever you have a piece of code that assigns a local variable, that local variable is assigned `nil` even if that piece of code is not evaluated. In your code line 2:

```
baz || baz = 0
```

the first `baz` returned an error because no such variable was assigned. Hence the assignment `baz = 0` that follows it was **not evaluated**, but nevertheless it was **parsed**, so in the context to follow, a local variable `baz` was created, and is initialized to `nil`.

With your second code chunk, `foo` is not assigned during `true if foo` and `foo`. After that, `foo = (true if foo)` has an assignment to `foo`, so even though `(true if foo)` is evaluated before assigment of `foo`, an error is not raised in that line.

Comment: Have to delete my comment as you've fixed your answer ;-) Now it's correct, assignment to baz is **not** performed but whenever Ruby **parser** detects an assignment, it allocates a space for it and sets to `nil`.

Comment: @DavidUnric You may have had something to say to my answer as it were earlier, but now, I don't think your comment adds any information beyond my answer.