# Extracting the last n characters from a ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

To get the last `n` characters from a string, I assumed you could use

```
ending = string[-n..-1]
```

but if the string is less than `n` letters long, you get `nil`.

What workarounds are available?

**Background**: The strings are plain ASCII, and I have access to ruby 1.9.1, and I'm using Plain Old Ruby Objects (no web frameworks).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Here you have a one liner, you can put a number greater than the size of the string:

```
"123".split(//).last(5).to_s
```

For ruby 1.9+

```
"123".split(//).last(5).join("").to_s
```

For ruby 2.0+, join returns a string

```
"123".split(//).last(5).join
```

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Ruby, you could use `chars` instead of split.

Comment: I used "12345678910".split(//).last(7).join.to_s

Comment: @Hard-BoiledWonderland `join` works. I don't think you need the last `to_s` if you use join.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You're right, for that case I used the above with Nokogiri `n.xpath('ReferenceID').inner_text.split(//).last(7).join.to_s.to_i` I needed the to_s to perform the to_i to extract the numeric value.

Comment: You are missing __.join__ - now it returns an array of strings. Instead it should be `"123".split(//).last(5).join` (Ruby 2.0.0)

Comment: If you're using rails, ActiveSupport defines String#last: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-last

Comment: would actually be better performance wise to write `"123".split(' ' ).join` in-place of using a regex pattern, but this is a solid breakdown. otherwise, might be nice to explain what `.split(//)` is doing.

Answer (score 125):

Well, the easiest workaround I can think of is:

```
ending = str[-n..-1] || str
```

(EDIT: The `or` operator has lower precedence than assignment, so be sure to use `||` instead.)

Comment: +1... I think this way is easier to read than `string.reverse[0..n].reverse`, which gives me a second of "wait, why is he doing that?" (or would if I weren't reading it in the context of this question)

Comment: Good answer, but it should be `||` instead of `or`, or put parentheses around `str[-n..-1] or str`.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't like that ruby doesn't treat s[-inf..-1] the same as x[0..inf]

Comment: Thanks for noting the operator precedence issue, Andrew. Gets me every time.

Comment: @perimosocordiae you aren't the only one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about

Comment: I like this solution because [] is so flexible to operate on any position of string.

Answer (score 79):

In straight Ruby (without Rails), you can do

```
string.chars.last(n).join
```

For example:

```
2.4.1 :009 > a = 'abcdefghij'
 => "abcdefghij"
2.4.1 :010 > a.chars.last(5).join
 => "fghij"
2.4.1 :011 > a.chars.last(100).join
 => "abcdefghij"
```

If you're using Ruby on Rails, you can call methods `first` and `last` on a string object.  These methods are preferred as they're succinct and intuitive.

For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = 'abcdefg'                                                                                                                
 => "abcdefg"
[2] pry(main)> a.first(3)                                                                                                                   
 => "abc"
[3] pry(main)> a.last(4)                                                                                                                    
 => "defg"
```

Comment: Ruby does not imply Rails.

Answer (score 14):

```
ending = string.reverse[0...n].reverse
```

Comment: This is the best approach I see on this page that satisfies the requirement of being able to supply an ending character length that exceeds the total string length.

Comment: For example, if you are intending to take the last 3 character of a group of stings like "abcde", "ab", and "a".  This technique will result in "cde", "ab", and "a" using the same code for each.  
`"abcde".reverse[0,3].reverse` >>> "cde"   `"ab".reverse[0,3].reverse` >>> "ab"   `"a".reverse[0,3].reverse` >>> "a"

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following code:

```
string[string.length-n,string.length]
```

Comment: code only - answers are not always helpful. explaining why/how this code is the fix would be great

Answer (score 6):

To get the last n characters from a string, you could do this

a[-n, n] if a is the array.

Here's and example if you would want one.

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > a = "911234567890"

=> "911234567890"

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > a[-5,5]

=> "67890"

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > a[-7,7]

=> "4567890"

Comment: If the number is too large, `nil` is returned, which is what this question was specifically trying to avoid.

Comment: Good answer. Clean.

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes? It has the exact same problem as what the OP was asking how to fix.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried a regex?

```
string.match(/(.{0,#{n}}$)/)
ending=$1
```

The regex captures as many characters it can at the end of the string, but no more than n. And stores it in $1.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using **Ruby on Rails**, you can simply do this:

```
str.last(n)
```

Note: I realize this doesn't answer the OP question because in PLAIN Ruby (w/o Rails) the `last` method does not exist for `String`.  For that, there are many other good answers here.

Comment: The `last` method does not exist for `String`. You should delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Improvement on EmFi's answer.

```
string[/.{,#{n}}\z/m]
```