# what is the best way to remove the last n characters of a string (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

in Ruby, 
I just want to get rid of the last *n* characters of a string, 
but the following doesn't work

```
"string"[0,-3]
```

nor

```
"string".slice(0, -3)
```

I'd like a clean method, not anything like

```
"string".chop.chop.chop
```

it may be trivial, please anyone teach me! thanks!

Comment: +1 for `chop.chop.chop`. Makes me think of you as taking an axe to the end of the string. :-)

Comment: `chop.chop.chop` has the added disadvantage of making three extra copies of your `String`. If it's just `"hello, world"`, then that won't matter, but if it's `File.read('/some/really/big.file')`, it will.

Comment: The opposite task, getting the last `n` bytes/characters/whatever from your string is slightly tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174767/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-ruby-string

Comment: See also: [Ruby, remove last N characters from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4209384/1591669)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use ranges.

```
"string"[0..-4]
```

Comment: You beat me to it! You can also do this with slice: "string".slice(0..-4)

Comment: hi, thanks! I just found that I made a mistake on the second parameter of [ ] or slice; it is length rather than the ending position...

Comment: Careful! In Ruby 1.8, this *does not* remove the last characters, it removes the last *bytes*!

Comment: this answer should explain the parameters.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a regex with gsub ...

```
"string".gsub( /.{3}$/, '' )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add an `!` to `slice` it will destructively remove the last n characters without having to assign it to another variable:

```
my_string.slice!(my_string.length-3,my_string.length)
```

compared to:

```
new = my_string.slice(0..-4)
```