# Ruby, remove last N characters from a string?

Tags: ruby, string

What is the preferred way of removing the last `n` characters from a string?

Comment: If you know the suffix (the top answer suggests a lot come here looking for this), you can use `delete_suffix` from Ruby 2.5. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209384/ruby-remove-last-n-characters-from-a-string/56803347#answer-56803347).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Ruby 2.5+

As of Ruby 2.5 you can use `delete_suffix` or `delete_suffix!` to achieve this in a fast and readable manner.

The docs on the methods are [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_suffix).

If you know what the suffix is, this is idiomatic (and I'd argue, even more readable than other answers here):

```
'abc123'.delete_suffix('123')     # => "abc"
'abc123'.delete_suffix!('123')    # => "abc"
```

It's even significantly faster (almost *40%* with the bang method) than the top answer. Here's the result of the same benchmark:

```
                     user     system      total        real
chomp            0.949823   0.001025   0.950848 (  0.951941)
range            1.874237   0.001472   1.875709 (  1.876820)
delete_suffix    0.721699   0.000945   0.722644 (  0.723410)
delete_suffix!   0.650042   0.000714   0.650756 (  0.651332)
```

I hope this is useful - note the method doesn't currently accept a regex so if you don't know the suffix it's not viable for the time being. However, as the accepted answer (*update: at the time of writing*) dictates the same, I thought this might be useful to some people.

Comment: @JPSilvashy I've never been more pleased to lose a checkmark.  This is a great answer.

Comment: This is a great and fast function, but this is not the right answer because it doesn't answer the question which is exactly `What is the preferred way of removing the last n characters from a string?`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Sam - this question's had an answer for almost nine years that worked the same as this one, with 261 upvotes at the time of writing. JP accepted that and recently switched to this, so I'd say it answered _their_ question :) I thought I'd pop this in as a modern alternative, and hope it helps people who land here. In fact, I've covered all this in the question - I'm hoping this method accepts a regex soon, though there's a perfect alternative for your case right below this.

Answer (score 354):

```
irb> 'now is the time'[0...-4]
=> "now is the "
```

Comment: Note that this only works in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, this will remove the last *bytes*, not the last *characters*.

Comment: But he probably meant *"bytes"* if he is using 1.8.x.

Comment: This does work, but I am finding 'abc123'.chomp('123')  to be twice as fast for both short and very long strings. (Ruby 2.0.0-p247)
Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: For those wondering why this specific example doesn't work..there are 3 dots not 2 ie `[0...-4]` not `[0..-4]`

Comment: Heh, well, I updated it for 3 dots, but both versions *worked.* Obviously the only question was whether the end of the range specified the index to keep (up to) or the last index to drop.

Comment: Actually, its eather `'now is the time'[0...-4]` (3 dots) yielding `now is the ` or `'now is the time'[0..-4]` (2 dots) yielding `now is the t`. As is, the answer is not completely correct.

Comment: Urk; good catch; fixed. It's correct now. Funny how no one remarked on that until you did.

Comment: @Plamarob I think it's more relevant to say that chomp is 53 nanoseconds faster than it is to say that it is twice as fast. Then you can better estimate the cost vs. value of using it, and whether it might be the thing to optimize in a given situation.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for n == 0. `"123"[0...-0]` is `""` instead of `"123"`

Answer (score 275):

If the characters you want to remove are always the same characters, then consider `chomp`:

```
'abc123'.chomp('123')    # => "abc"
```

The advantages of `chomp` are: no counting, and the code more clearly communicates what it is doing.

With no arguments, `chomp` removes the DOS or Unix line ending, if either is present:

```
"abc\n".chomp      # => "abc"
"abc\r\n".chomp    # => "abc"
```

---

*From the comments, there was a question of the speed of using `#chomp` versus using a range. Here is a benchmark comparing the two:*

```
require 'benchmark'

S = 'asdfghjkl'
SL = S.length
T = 10_000
A = 1_000.times.map { |n| "#{n}#{S}" }

GC.disable

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('chomp') { T.times { A.each { |s| s.chomp(S) } } }
  x.report('range') { T.times { A.each { |s| s[0...-SL] } } }
end
```

Benchmark Results (using CRuby 2.13p242):

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
chomp   1.540000   0.040000   1.580000 (  1.587908)
range   1.810000   0.200000   2.010000 (  2.011846)
-------------------------------- total: 3.590000sec

            user     system      total        real
chomp   1.550000   0.070000   1.620000 (  1.610362)
range   1.970000   0.170000   2.140000 (  2.146682)
```

So chomp is faster than using a range, by ~22%.

Comment: Chop is also an option. It's less fussy about what gets removed.

Comment: algorithmically, wouldn't something like [0..-#] be faster? a chomp has to parse a string looking for matches. Excluding and end char number doesn't.

Comment: where would be the most appropriate place my benchmarked results?

Comment: I found the opposite is actually true. 
The reality is that .chomp seems consistently to be twice as fast.

Comment: @Plamarob, Benchmarks in Ruby are often surprising.  I'm so often wrong that I no longer try to guess what will be faster.  Also, if the answer would be improved by the benchmark results, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: If I'm reading the code right, range takes about 53 nanoseconds longer than chomp. It may be a significant drag in certain situations, but keeping the absolute speed in mind (rather than just the relative) might tell you whether you should go through your codebase and change all your ranges into chomps (where applicable). Probably not.

Comment: Works great. And you can use `chomp!()` to act on the String in-place.

Answer (score 65):

```
str = str[0..-1-n]
```

Unlike the `[0...-n]`, this handles the case of n=0.

Comment: Note that this only works in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, this will remove the last *bytes*, not the last *characters*.

Comment: This is better than the chosen answer, since 3 dots (...) is easier to memorize since -n means take out n characters from the end of the string.

Comment: also "abcd"[0..-2] #=> "abc" while "abcd"[0...-2] #=> "ab". In my opinion the 3 dots range option results in a more self explanatory code.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for n == 0. `str[0...-0]` is `""` instead of `"123"`. You actually want `str[0..-(n+1)]`

Comment: @movermeyer your edit was rejected by JS and Bash fans. I'm sorry, SO is **** and 90% of people are here only to reject the edits, close and delete questions and answers. You can read my profile info for more and to understand why I'm not an active contributor anymore. You've spotted a real bug in my answer made 11 years ago, well done. I've reaccepted the edit and changed it a bit.

Answer (score 32):

I would suggest `chop`. I think it has been mentioned in one of the comments but without links or explanations so here's why I think it's better:

It simply removes the last character from a string and you don't have to specify any values for that to happen.

If you need to remove more than one character then `chomp` is your best bet. This is what the [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chop) have to say about `chop`:

> Returns a new String with the last character removed. If the string
>   ends with \r\n, both characters are removed. Applying chop to an empty
>   string returns an empty string. String#chomp is often a safer
>   alternative, as it leaves the string unchanged if it doesn’t end in a
>   record separator.

Although this is used mostly to remove separators such as `\r\n` I've used it to remove the last character from a simple string, for example the `s` to make the word singular.

Comment: Wouldn't that just remove that single last character? The question is about "characters" in plural

Comment: Yes, you're right, but chomp('chars') will remove the last 'chars'. It wasn't clear to me if the OP wanted specific characters or just N characters.

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer, only when you want to remove only one character (which was the case with me though).

Answer (score 30):

```
name = "my text"
x.times do name.chop! end
```

Here in the console:

```
>name = "Nabucodonosor"
 => "Nabucodonosor" 
> 7.times do name.chop! end
 => 7 
> name
 => "Nabuco"
```

Comment: Is this efficient? Seems one worth a benchmark comparison to other answers :)

Answer (score 18):

Dropping the last `n` characters is the same as keeping the first `length - n` characters.

Active Support includes [`String#first`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String%3Afirst) and [`String#last`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String%3Alast) methods which provide a convenient way to keep or drop the first/last `n` characters:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/access'

"foobarbaz".first(3)  # => "foo"
"foobarbaz".first(-3) # => "foobar"
"foobarbaz".last(3)   # => "baz"
"foobarbaz".last(-3)  # => "barbaz"
```

Comment: Rails 6.0 has a deprication wraning on `"foobarbaz".first(-3)` "Calling String#first with a negative integer limit will raise an ArgumentError in Rails 6.1."

Answer (score 7):

if you are using rails, try:

```
"my_string".last(2) # => "ng"
```

[EDITED]

To get the string WITHOUT the last 2 chars:

```
n = "my_string".size
"my_string"[0..n-3] # => "my_stri"
```

Note: the last string char is at n-1. So, to remove the last 2, we use n-3.

Comment: This doesn't remove the last two letters. It returns them.

Comment: You don't need to measure the string first, ruby uses negative indexes from the end of the string natively

Answer (score 5):

Check out the `slice()` method:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-slice

Comment: Note that this only works in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, this will remove the last *bytes*, not the last *characters*.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use something like

```
 "string".sub!(/.{X}$/,'')
```

Where `X` is the number of characters to remove.

Or with assigning/using the result:

```
myvar = "string"[0..-X]
```

where `X` is the number of characters **plus one** to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with creating class methods and want the characters you chop off, try this:

```
class String
  def chop_multiple(amount)
    amount.times.inject([self, '']){ |(s, r)| [s.chop, r.prepend(s[-1])] }
  end
end

hello, world = "hello world".chop_multiple 5
hello #=> 'hello '
world #=> 'world'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
str = 'string'
n = 2  #to remove last n characters

str[/\A.{#{str.size-n}}/] #=> "stri"
```

Answer (score -4):

```
x = "my_test"
last_char = x.split('').last
```

Comment: question was about removing last N characters from a string, not about finding the last character