# delete dash character which is at the end of the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have table items in my db.
I want in Item.name replace `-` character which is at the end of the `Item.name` 
So I try to do it like this:

```
 items = Item.all
 items.each do |it|
 it.name=it.name.gsub('/\-$/','')
 it.save
 end
```

But it doesn't work. What do I do?

upd:
I managed to do it like this:

```
i = Item.all
 i.each do |it|
 it.name=it.name.chomp('-')
 it.save
 end
```

But still don't get why first variant didn't work

Comment: why do you try to use a regexp when there's no need to ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sub!` function of ruby.

Ex.

> it.name.sub!("-","")

`!` represent as Bang method, so you not need store it again on `item` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one it will definatly work for you.

```
items = Item.all
 items.each do |item|
 item.name = item.name.gsub('-','')
 it.save
 end
```

Comment: That will remove dashes from anywhere in the `name` string, not only the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like:

```
items = Item.all
 items.each do |it|
 if name.end_with? '-'
   it.name=it.name[0..-2]
 else
   it.name=it.name
 end
 it.save
 end
```

OR you should use this

```
 items = Item.all
 items.each do |it|
 it.name=it.name.chomp('-')  
 it.save
 end
```

Comment: I need to replace `-` character which is located at the end of the string only! your function will replace all `-` characters!

Comment: I have made some changes in my code please make sure for that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer : [Ruby, remove last N characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209384/ruby-remove-last-n-characters-from-a-string)

so you just have to use the `chomp` method :

In your example :

```
items = Item.all
items.each do |it|
it.name=it.name.chomp
it.save
end
```