# What is Ruby's equivalent of substr?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to implement the following code in Ruby and getting stuck on it.

I've looked at documentation but they all deal with a string rather than an object.

PHP code:

```
if ( substr($new_price, -2) != '00' ) {
```

Ruby code I tried:

```
if new_price[-2,2] != '00'
if new_price.to_s.slice[-2,2] != '00'
```

---

Edit:

For current usage, which is just to check to see if a price has decimals or not, I switched to this:

```
if new_price.ceil != new_price
```

I am still curious how to do this properly in Ruby.

Comment: If it's an object, operate on a *property* of that object. Don't rely on what may be an arbitrary `to_s` implementation that could conceivably change.

Comment: I thought Ruby treated everything as an object? In php I would just call this a variable

Comment: Everything *is* an object, including strings. Slicing an arbitrary object makes no sense. Slicing a `to_s` representation is risky, because it could change. If `new_price` is a string, you can use the array-notation slice, `[n1..n2]`. If it's some other type, you should operate on whatever part of it you care about, or redefine its `slice` method and/or its `[]` operator. Both horrible ideas, because the do not communicate what you're actually doing, which is getting the cents portions of the price.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting the last n characters from a ruby string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174767/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-ruby-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby you can get the last two elements of a string with (for example) this code:

```
price = '200'
puts price[-2..-1]
#=> 00
```

You could also add the `last(n)` method to the String class, like so:

```
class String
  def last(n)
    self[-n..-1] || self
  end
end
```

Then you could write code like this:

```
puts price.last(2)
#=> 00

puts price.last(100)
#=> 200
```

Comment: aye I can do it if I explicitly state the string, but what about on object?

Comment: `price` is an instance of the `String class` in our example - that means that you get the last method on any String instance you will create/have created (like eg name = "", description = "", etc). And while defining the `last` method on the concrete object is possible via a singleton method (`def price.last(n)
  self[-n..-1] || self
end`), it would not make sense in our example - you could not call it on any other string instance, just the one and only price instance...

Comment: @DougMcK Slicing arbitrary objects makes no sense. You could redefine `slice` on whatever class you want, but it's horribly non-communicative and counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
unless new_price.to_s.end_with?('00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if new_price.to_s.slice(-2, 2) != '00'
```

Comment: [] and () would do 2 completely different things