# Ruby: Why does 'and not' work when '&& !(expr)' does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an if statement in my Rails app. I need to do a basic "if true and !false" sort of check. The expression is defined as:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'settings' && !Settings.setting_is_set?('defaults_set')
```

If I put that as my expression to an if, the if will not trigger. If I run that expression in the console, I get false.

Now, if I modify the expression to read:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'settings' and not Settings.setting_is_set?('defaults_set')
```

It returns true as it should, and the executes it's block.

So the question is: Why is 'expression && !expression' not behaving like 'expression and not expression'. It's my understanding && and ! should correspond to and and not almost directly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: More than likely this is due to operator precedence. I'm pretty clear on this in PHP and Python, but not Ruby - hopefully someone who knows Ruby better than I will come and explain how it works in Ruby.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2083112/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because when you use `&&` Ruby is interpreting the entire end of the string as a single argument being passed to `include`. Put parenthesis around the `'settings'` and the first statement will work fine:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'settings' && !Settings.setting_is_set?('defaults_set')
# => false

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('settings') && !Settings.setting_is_set?('defaults_set')
# => true
```

Somehow, when you use `and not` it knows that the second part is not part of what is being passed to `include` and your call succeeds.

Comment: `and` has lower precedence than `&&`. This is a common ruby gotcha: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about

Comment: I never use and/or, only &&/||.  In most languages you expect these constructs to have high precedence; and/or don't.

Answer (score 1):

`‘not’` is a control operator, `!` is a logical operator. The difference is that ‘not’ has lower priority when evaluating the command. Use `!` when you do logical expressions.