# In Ruby why won't `foo = true unless defined?(foo)` make the assignment?

Tags: ruby

What's going on here?  What is the subtle difference between the two forms of "unless"?

```
> irb(main):001:0> foo = true unless defined?(foo)
=> nil 
irb(main):002:0> unless defined?(fooo) ; fooo = false ; end
=> false
```

thx

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: With all this talk of assigning variables unless they're already defined, I feel compelled to point out that `foo ||= true` accomplishes the same thing (and always returns `true`).

Comment: @Allison R. Not if `foo` is defined but false.

Comment: Instead of using a vague title such as "What's going on here in ruby?", I'd recommend you use a more descriptive one. At the very least, you should include the word "unless" in the title. This way if someone runs into the same problem, they can know that this question might be related based on the question's title.

Comment: The nicer way to do this with in one line is `defined?(foo) or foo = true`.

Comment: Stumbled on this problem. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, ruby creates local variable at parse time setting them to `nil`so it is defined and this is done whether the code is executed or not.

When the code is evaluated at your first line, it doesn't execute the assignment part since `foo` is set to `nil`. In the second line, because `fooo` has not been parsed yet, `defined?`returns `nil` letting the code inside the block execute and assign `fooo`.

As an example you can try this:

```
if false  
  foo = 43  
end  
defined? foo  
=> "local-variable"
```

This is taken from a forum [post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193638#843926) at ruby-forum.

Comment: Excellent example - should have thought about simplifying the problem further to the one you showed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Let's start with something simpler:

```
# z is not yet defined
irb(main):001:0> defined?(z)
=> nil

# Even though the assignment won't execute,
# the mere presence of the assignment statement
# causes z to come to life.
irb(main):002:0> z = 123 if false
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> defined?(z)
=> "local-variable"
irb(main):004:0> z
=> nil
```

Now we can figure out your first example.

```
foo = true unless defined?(foo)
```

Is `foo` defined? Before we press ENTER in `irb`, no. However, the presence of the assignment statement causes `foo` to come to life. That means the assignment statement **won't** be executed, leaving `foo` in existence but having `nil` as its value. And what is the last expression evaluated in the `irb` line? It is `unless defined?(foo)`, which evaluates to `nil`.

For more info on how assignments (even those that do not get executed) cause variables to exist, see this discussion of [Variable/Method Ambiguity](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#variablemethodambiguity).

In your second example, there is nothing mysterious at all: `fooo` is not defined, so the code in the block executes, setting `fooo` to `false`. That assignment is the last expression evaluated, so `false` is the return value of our block.

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main)> foo = true unless defined?(Integer)
=> nil 
irb(main)> foo = true unless defined?(thisIsUndefined)
=> true
```

Your first block is returning `nil` because the way it's written leaves 2 options:

- `foo` is not defined  --> assign true
- `foo` is defined  --> do nothing

Here, foo must be defined when the line is evaluated.  Thus, nothing happens and `nil` is returned.

```
irb(main)> unless defined?(Integer) ; fooo = false ; end
=> nil
irb(main)> unless defined?(thisIsUndefined) ; fooo = false ; end
=> false
```

Your second block operates the same way your first one does.  If `fooo` is not defined, the block is entered and `fooo` is set to `false`.  The result of the last line of the block is the return value of the block, thus the `false` you are seeing.  If `fooo` does exist, then the block is skipped over and nothing happens, therefore there is nothing to return, therefore the `nil`.

Based on your code, I would say that `foo` was defined when this code was run and `fooo` was not (test code shown was generated in Ruby 1.8.6).  If you did not define either of these before running this code, then you may have something called `foo` that is defined by default (do `defined?(foo)` by itself to check).  Try using a different name and see if you get the same results.

**Edit:**

```
irb(main)> defined?(bar)
=> nil
irb(main)> bar = true unless defined?(bar)
=> nil
irb(main)> defined?(bar)
=> "local-variable"
```

Apparently, `defined?()` is returning true since it has already seen `bar` (at the beginning of the line), even though you are still in the process of defining it.

Answer (score 1):

in the first instance you call `foo` into existence in the assignment statement. Maybe this will clarify:

```
bar = if true
         puts bar.class
      else
         puts "not reached"
      end
NilClass
=> nil

baz = if true
         puts baz.class
         42
      else
         puts "not reached"
      end
NilClass
=> 42
```

Answer (score 1):

August, all look fine in 1.8.7:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> unless defined?(fooo); fooo = true; end
=> true
irb(main):002:0> fooo
=> true
irb(main):003:0> `ruby --version`
=> "ruby 1.8.7 (2008-06-20 patchlevel 22) [i486-linux]\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well.. One form is a block and one form isn't. The second part, the block, returns the last statement evaluated. The first one.. Hrm.. I don't know exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby 1.8.7:

```
foo = true unless defined?(foo)
p foo # => nil

unless defined?(fooo); fooo = true; end
p foo # => nil
```

I don't have an explanation for the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: `fooo` (as opposed to `foo`) is true.