# In Ruby on Rails, passing locals to a view, defaulting to true, won't work with ||=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, default-value

if the code is

```
do_more ||= true
```

then when `false` is passed in, it becomes

```
do_more = false || true
```

and therefore will still be true.  So this is one case where `foo ||= default_value` won't work?  In this case it will need to be

```
do_more = true if !defined? do_more
```

?

Comment: Related question: [In Ruby why won't `foo = true unless defined?(foo)` make the assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291646/in-ruby-why-wont-foo-true-unless-definedfoo-make-the-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, `foo ||= default_value` never works if a valid value for foo is false.

`foo ||= default_value` is only a valid pattern when *all* valid values are interpreted as boolean TRUE.

Your statement of `do_more == true if !defined? do_more` should use the assignment operator, I presume a typo: `do_more = true if !defined? do_more`

Maybe better would be `do_more = true unless defined? do_more`

That looks ok to me, but you need to test to ensure that it works correctly.

If your param is coming in from an HTML form, then the undefined case is actually a zero length string, "". If that is your situation, then you'd want:

`do_more = true if do_more == ''`

I'd also suggest a comment # set default

Comment: yes it was a typo.  so in other words, if you ever need to pass in a `nil` or `false`, you cannot use `foo ||= some_value`.  I am not so used to `unless` since I have been using `if` for 28 years.  I need an extra few seconds to understand it as opposed to immediately if using `if`

Comment: `do_more = true unless defined? do_more` won't work: see [In Ruby why won't `foo = true unless defined?(foo)` make the assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291646/in-ruby-why-wont-foo-true-unless-definedfoo-make-the-assignment)

Comment: @Jian Lin: I hear you re if. But more importantly for this situation, see @Andrew Grimm's comment. In similar circumstances, I've redefined variables to be in the negative so that the omitted value (nil) can be used as the default. Here, that'd be "do_no_more" rather than "do_more". @Andrew: +1 Thanks.