# Does it matter if a conditional statement comes before or after the expression?

Tags: ruby, syntax, if-statement, conditional-statements

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm a C# guy fumbling his way around ruby..

in ruby i notice a lot of people do this:

```
do_something(with params) if 1 = 1
```

is there any difference (even slight) between that and this:

```
if 1 = 1 do_something(with params)
```

or is it the same thing written for better clarity?

Comment: It's mostly stylistic. When dealing with a single line of code I use the trailing conditional as it seems to make more sense conversationally. Since a large component of writing software is making it maintainable, I try to write it in a way that allows it to slide into the brain easily. Some books recommend using a block or wrapping conditional `if (blah) ... some code ... end` only, arguing that it's better for future expansion of the code. If we need to add something the closing `end` is already there. I find it plenty easy with my vim-powers to work around that so I use single-line mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's syntactic sugar... allowing us to write code in a way that's easier to read.

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_syntactic_sugar.html

Note: for @Phrogz, the following are NOT the same!
Please make sure that you are not trying to assign a value to variable instead of comparing a variable to a value! Also, as Phrogz mentions, the order of variable assignment makes a big difference... see @Phrogz answer for mor details!

```
if 1 = 1 then do_something(with params) end
if 1 == 1 then do_something(with params) end
```

Answer (score 7):

The latter is syntactically invalid. You would need to write:

```
if 1==1 then do_something(with params) end
```

Single-line conditionals must always trail. And **yes, there is a difference**. Try these out:

```
bar1 = if foo1=14
  foo1*3
end
#=> 42

bar2 = foo2*3 if foo2=14
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo2' for main:Object
```

In the latter, Ruby sees the assignment after the reference and so treats `foo2` as a method instead of a local variable. This is only an issue when:

- You are intentionally using assignment (not testing for equality) in a conditional, and
- This is the first time (in terms of source order) that this variable has been assigned in the scope.

Comment: `warning: found = in conditional, should be ==`

Comment: @JonasElfström Yes, there is also that. But the issue remains. It is (I find personally and in others code) common in Ruby to use assignment in conditionals. `if user=User.find(42) then ... end`. Sadly, the heuristics for local variables don't work when the assignment is in a single-line trailing conditional.

Comment: @Phrogz, I'm trying to understand why the assignment in the trailing conditional fails. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @Leito The problem is that Ruby's interpreter uses a heuristic to decide if an unqualified, unadorned name is a local variable or a method call, since for `foo = bar` the `bar` could be a local variable or a method call with no arguments. As I understand it, the heuristic is based on how the name is used the first time it is seen lexically in the source code. In the problematic case, it decides that `foo2` is a method call instead of a local variable, and it is assumed to be such from that point forward.

Comment: @Leito For example, this horrible hack makes it work again: `bar = (foo||=0) && (foo*3) if foo=14` because now the first time it sees `foo` it knows that it must be a local variable and not a method call. Alternatively, just putting `foo=nil` on the line before also fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

Fire up `irb` and run your code and you will learn:

- 1=1 is a syntax error, change to 1==1.
- You can't have an expression directly after `if 1==1`, you will have to add a `:` or `then` and close with an `end`.

The trailing `if` should really only be used for single expressions and you can't add an `else`. They are called *statement modifiers* and they are just syntactic sugar for better readability. I'm not totally against them but recommend using them sparingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either but if you put the if statement first then you will need to close the condition with an 'end'.

```
if 1==1 
   do_something(with params)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The following leaves `foo` as nil.

```
foo = true unless defined?(foo) #Leaves foo as nil
```

This is because Ruby creates a variable `foo` and assigns it to nil when it reads (parsing, I think) the `foo = true` bit, and then when it reads (executing, I think) the `unless defined?(foo)`, it says that `foo` is defined (it's defined as nil), and therefore doesn't execute the `foo = true` part.

If you did

```
unless defined?(foo)
  foo = true
end
```

then you'd get `foo` assinged to true.

I added this to [What are the Ruby Gotchas a newbie should be warned about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about/3654862#3654862), because someone got confused about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291646/in-ruby-why-wont-foo-true-unless-definedfoo-make-the-assignment).

So yes, in some circumstances it can matter.