# Is the order of each_value for Ruby's hashes defined?

Tags: ruby, associative-array

Is the order of the values returned by Ruby's `Hash::each_value{ |val| block }` somehow defined? I.e. for a given hash is the order of values in the iterations of the loop always* the same?

I wonder if it is so, as the key-value pairs of hashes are not sorted unlike the values of an array.

Given the following example:

```ruby
myhash = { :a => 100, :b => 200, :z => 9, :e => 101 }
myhash.each_value { |val|
  puts val
}
```

Does Ruby ensure it always* prints

```
100
200
9
101
```

---

**Bonus question in case it is defined:**
What are the prerequisites that the order is defined? Does it only apply for hard-coded hashes as the example?

---

[*]: "*always*" should be read as '*on each execution and on any system with a working Ruby 1.9+*'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Ruby's array of 1000 hashes' key and value pairs are always in a particular order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516125/why-rubys-array-of-1000-hashes-key-and-value-pairs-are-always-in-a-particular)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8, Hashes are not ordered and the values will be returned in an arbitrary order that you cannot depend upon. In Ruby 1.9, Hashes are ordered based on the time the keys were inserted (first insertion positioned first, etc...).

You specified in a footnote that "'always' should be read as 'on each execution and on any system with a working Ruby 1.9+'.". By that definition of "always", the answer is "yes" ;)

From the [Ruby 1.8.7 Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html) docs:

> The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem
>   arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order.

From the [Ruby 1.9.3 Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) docs:

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer. I was sure I read the docu, but obviously not carefully enough.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.9 the order is insertion order.

Some info from ~three years ago when this was news:

- [YCombinator discussed a possible usecase](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=466592)
- [And some internals info](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/)

Comment: @Torbjoern No problem; I saw Ben was providing the doc links, so I figured I'd go for something other than API docs :)