# Why can't I do "if zero" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
>> current_user.first_visit
=> 0
>> if current_user.first_visit
>> puts "test"
>> end
test
=> nil
```

Why does it print test?

Comment: It looks like your question has been answered.  But you should stop using numeric values for true/false.  Use the keywords true and false if your language supports them

Comment: Rails has extended the integer type. You can also use "if current_user.first_visit.zero?"

Comment: @vise: `.zero?` is plain old ruby: [APIdock.com link](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_6_287/Numeric/zero%3F)

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of [What are the Ruby Gotchas a newbie should be warned about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Ruby only `nil` can be considered as analogue to `false`. There is no assumption, that `0`, `""` or `[]` means `false`, so you must use `== 0`, `.blank?`, `.empty?`, `.zero?`, etc.

But `nil` doesn't always behave as `false`. For example, in string interpolation, the `.to_s` method is applied to `#{}` contents, that works differently for `FalseClass` and `NilClass`:

```
irb(main)> "qwe #{false} rty"
=> "qwe false rty"
irb(main)> "qwe #{nil} rty"
=> "qwe  rty"
```

Comment: Please note that `.blank?` , `.empty?` are extensions provided by Rails framework (through `activesupport`) and not available in Ruby Standard or Core Lib.
Also the different behaviour is because "#{false}" calls the `to_s` method.

Comment: @swanand: `zero?` and `empty?` are there in core lib (not sure which classes you had in mind, though).

Comment: @pdom's edit was correct. IDK, why others rejected it. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7845176

Answer (score 6):

You can think of Ruby's if as testing either a boolean, or for the *availability* of data (vs `nil`).  The implicit conversion from 0 to false supported by C and (hence other languages like C++) was more an historical artefact from days before C had a distinct boolean type.  There, it relies on 0 being a convenient sentinel value or having an intuitive meaning.  For many things (e.g. some country where clothing sizes range from 0 to 8, POSIX libC function call results) zero does not convert nicely to a logically equivalent boolean, so it's not a bad thing that Ruby goes its own way.

From this perspective, the issue with your code is that current_user.first_visit - the name of which implies a boolean type - actually holds 0 and not false.  Alternatively, if you had the clearly numeric current_user.visit_counter, it would be natural and correct to use one of:

```
current_user.visit_counter > 0
current_user.visit_counter >= 1
current_user.visit_counter != 0
```

Comment: I'd say that this is very inconvenient especially when you come from other languages, 0 is almost always treated as falsy value, just makes it harder to work with ruby

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
>> current_user.first_visit
=> 0
>> if current_user.first_visit != 0
>> puts "test"
>> else
>> puts "fail"
>> end
fail
=>nil
```

When checking for numeric values you also need to match it with the expected value