# How to enable Ruby warnings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings

I did this in `test.rb`:

```
def some_method
  p "First definition"
end

def some_method
  p "Second definition"
end

some_method
```

When I call `ruby test.rb`, it prints `Second definition` (expected)

When I call `ruby -w test.rb`, it prints `Second definition` (expected) *and* prints a warning `test.rb:5: warning: method redefined; discarding old some_method`

Is there a way to enable those warnings in Rails? (and print the warning to the console/log file)

*Why I would like to enable warnings*: For example if I inadvertently *re-define* a method in a controller, then I would be aware of the problem by looking at the warning printed to the console/log file. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about/5508658#5508658).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this somewhere in your initialisation code (such as `config/application.rb`):

```
$VERBOSE = true
```

You'll probably also get some warnings from Rails itself though.

Comment: This helps as a starter, thanks. I will look for some way (if possible!) to turn off the warnings for the Rails/3rd party code! I've written a log highlighter, so maybe I will highlight in the console, in red, the source code directory of *my* app, so I can pay attention to it whild ignoring the the myriads of warnings from Rails.

Comment: @Zabba did you end up finding a way to do this?

Comment: @patrick-davey, no. But today I found this blog http://mislav.net/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/ (ironically written 1 month after I had this problem; why didn't I find it back then?! heh.)