# Why does this evaluate to false? "S" == /[S]/ => 0

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm a ruby newbie and I'm having trouble understanding why `"S" == /[S]/`  evaluates to `false`. 
Can anyone explain this? I've also tried

```
"S" =~ /[S]/
#=> 0  `

"S" =~ /[^S]/ 
#=> nil
```

baffling to me

Comment: Because `'S'` (`String`) isn't equal to `/[S]/` (`Regexp`).

Comment: `0` is not falsy in ruby.

Comment: Sidenote: remember that in Ruby (unlike in C) an integer of '0' means logical 'true', so `"S" =~ /[S]/ => 0` does NOT MEAN FALSE. It means true. `if(0)` runs the code. `if(nil)` and `if(false)` does not.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl `/[^S]/` - means anything except S.

Comment: @BroiSatse: right, I was writing too fast, thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Ruby Gotchas a newbie should be warned about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about) --- I vote for it because the first post in that topic explicitely says about zeros being considered `true`.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It is not duplicate because it is too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"S" == /[S]/` is false because `==` in Ruby doesn't evaluate whether a regexp matches, it just determines whether two objects are equal. The string `"S"` and the regexp `/[S]/` are of course completely different objects and not equal.

`=~` (which is a correct way to match a regexp against a string in Ruby) returns the match position. In your first example the match position is the beginning of the string, 0. In the second example there is no match, so `=~` returns nil.

Comment: How would I get "S" =~ /[S]/
#=> 0  to return true instead?    Also I thought the ^ character means starting charcter

Comment: 0 is what Ruby calls "truthy" -- it is treated as true in conditionals and such. If you really need to turn it in to boolean true, do `!! ("S" =~ /[S]/)`. Regarding ^, at the beginning of a regexp it means the beginning of the matched string, but inside [] it means "not the following character".

Answer (score 1):

```
"S" == /[S]/
```

Everything (almost) in Ruby is an object. In this case you are checking for equality between an instance of a String `"S"` and an instance of a Regexp `/[S]/`. Therefore, by definition, they are two different objects, hence the expression returns false. Rather than checking for equality with `==` you should use `=~`

```
"S" == /[S]/
```

When you use a match operator `=~` it returns the index of the first match found in a string. Remember that indexing in Ruby starts from 0. In your example the first character in the provided string is matched. The first character is indexed with `0` and that is what the statement returns.

```
"S" == /[^S]/
```

By using a caret `^` you are telling Ruby to match anything but what is between square brackets (this is only true in square brackets, `^` is also used to indicate the beginning of a string if used outside `[]`). In your case it is anything but `S`. Ruby does not find a match and returns `nil`.